# Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral for the expected value of a die

Tags: probability, integration, lebesgue-integral, stieltjes-integral

I am learning [Lebesgue–Stieltjes integration](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrale_di_Lebesgue-Stieltjes) and decided to test myself computing the expected value of a 6-sided die roll "from scratch".

I know to obtain the expected value I need to compute:

$$\mathbb E(x) = \int x \,dg(x)$$

and I know $g(x)$ is the Cumulative Distribution Function:

$$\begin{equation*}
g(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & x \in (-\infty, 1) \\
\frac{1}{6} & x \in [1, 2) \\
\frac{2}{6} & x \in [2, 3) \\
& \vdots \\
1 & x \in [6, \infty)
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}$$

But I am stuck there. My questions are:

- what is $x$ in this case? The outcome of the die roll? Its density function?
- can we say that the integrand function is *simple*? In the case of simple functions I know we can use this formula:

  $${\displaystyle \int s\,\mathrm {d} \mu _{w}=\sum _{i}a_{i}\mu _{w}(A_{i})}  $$

  so the result of the integral will be:

  $$\frac{1}{6} \cdot a_1 + \frac{2}{6} \cdot a_2 + \dots + 1 \cdot a_6 $$

  but I do not know what $a_i$s are.

So my question is: what is the step by step method of calculating $\mathbb E(die)$ with Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral?

Comment: This is a discrete distribution, not a continuous.  It does not lend itself to this sort of methodology.  Of course you can make up something that will match the desired answer, but that's circular.

Comment: Stieltjes integral is know for handling both discrete and continuous distributions, that is why I am studying it.

Comment: Well, if you are ok with writing your distribution as  a (weighted) sum of delta functions, do that.  Of course, in that case you just get back the usual sum.